# Cloud Function is not returning and Unreasonable issue throwing by PARSE Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Actually my Requirement is Simply store the data and pass stored data in callback. Here am not handling any **Date** things. Because Parse crash StrackTrace is saying crash is happing the conversion between Date as String. But this thing i don't care. Because i am not handling any date in Client side

**// The following code is Objective C:**

```
- (IBAction)didTapStoreButton:(id)sender {

        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        params[@"userObjectId"] = [[PFUser currentUser] objectId];
        params[@"name"] = @"apple";

        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"vendorCloudFunc"
                           withParameters:params
                                    block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                        PFObject *pfObject = object;
                                        if (object) {
                                            NSLog(@"pfObject: %@",pfObject);

                                        } else {
                                            NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
                                        }
                                    }];
    }

// The following code is Cloud Function in Parse :
    Parse.Cloud.define("vendorCloudFunc", function(request, status) {
        var toSaves = [];
        var MySpecialObject = Parse.Object.extend("newclass");
        var myObject = new MySpecialObject();
            myObject.set("userObjectId",request.params["userObjectId"]);
            myObject.set("name",request.params["name"]);
           toSaves.push(myObject);
        console.log('## myObject: '+myObject);
        Parse.Object.saveAll(toSaves, {
            success: function(saveList) {
            console.log('## newClass first Record:'+saveList[0]);
                status.success(saveList[0]);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                status.error("Unable to save objects.")
            }
        });
        });
```

[image: Check this screenshot. **Crash is happening in Parse Framework**]

I don't have clue, Why this crash is happening.?

Comment: Something is deallocated while there is still a reference to it, you just need to work out what and where from. Time for a zombie hunt...

Comment: @Wain okay.. but i wrote very straight forward code. i did not see any Object still alive. Can you tell me. How do i find, Who's still Alive?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing NSDate instance instead of NSString instance as "string" argument, so there's no UTF8String method in NSDate.

Comment: No am not using any NSDate related stuff. If you check with that Screenshot. Parse Framework ie. PFDateFormmater class throws me this Error.